# How to extend pandas with functions that are ready for column / list of columns parameter?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, customization

There is a nice library pandas-flavor https://pypi.org/project/pandas-flavor/ that allows to extend pandas.

I've wrote toy-example like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_flavor as pf
from scipy import stats


df = pd.DataFrame(data={
  "x": ['a', 'a', 'b'],
  "y": [0, 2, 5],
  "z": [5, 0, 7],
})


@pf.register_dataframe_method
def to_frame(df):
  return df

@pf.register_dataframe_method
def custom_func(df, grouping, c):
  return df.groupby(grouping)[c].transform(stats.zscore).to_frame().max(axis=1)
```

Basically, `c` parameter now could be a single column (string) or list of columns for `custom_func` (main goal):

```
df.custom_func(['x'], 'y')
df.custom_func(['x'], ['y'])
df.custom_func(['x'], ['y', 'z'])
```

A few remarks:

- for single column `df.groupby(grouping)[c].transform(stats.zscore)` returns `Series` for which `max(axis=1)` gives error, unless you make it into `DataFrame` (`to_frame()`)
- for multiple columns `df.groupby(grouping)[c].transform(stats.zscore)`gives `DataFrame` but there is no `to_frame()` for it, so I've added it by pandas-flavor

It works, but the question is:

- could it be done simpler or in more standard way ?
- is there a standard way to write functions that are ready for single/multiple columns ?

Comment: `if isinstance(c, list): return xxx else: return yyy` is the normal pattern when specifics need to change based on params

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to avoid "if" with some other pandas magick than my hack?

Comment: for dynamically typed languages it's not a hack :-). It's an established coding pattern